# Convert between IEEE decimal (BCD) and Microsoft System.Decimal

Tags: c#, decimal

Does anyone know of a routine to convert between an IEEE decimal (preferably in BCD format) and a System.Decimal?

I'm looking for something better than converting to and from a string and would prefer not to hand code a solution.

Thus far I haven't even been able to find a definitive description of Microsofts [System.Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx), but the linked description explains enough to know the format is not the same.

Comment: the linked microsof page describes the binary forat for System.Decimal. find documentation of "IEEE decimal" and there you are. then just the coding is left.